# Boolean and geometry nodes don't mix

Tags: geometry-nodes, boolean-modifier

[image]I'm still learning Blender. And I've been on it for a while trying stuff out. But I ran into a problem that the internet has a hard time showing me.

I've made an object(wall) using a tutorial that uses geometry nodes and I needed to make a hole in it, but boolean doesn't work on it and I have that "realize instances" before the "instance of points". It cuts through all the other simple objects in the same scene. Am I doing something wrong? Or is it just what it is?

[image]

Comment: Please add some screenshots of your setup like the node tree. You say you add "realize instances" **before** the "instance on points", which is wrong, you should add it **after** instead.

Comment: Hello. I have added a screenshot and a screenshot of the wall I need to cut through. And I'm sure I have followed the tut to the exact number, unless I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: You need another "Realize Instances" just before "Group Output". If the boolean still doesn't work, try the "Mesh Boolean" node within geometry nodes. Also, I would test the boolean with a much smaller number of hexagons first.

Comment: Epic!! Thank you. It works. It does take the multi-colour away. But I don't care. I just needed that to be cut. And Now I can continue with this weird thing I'm making.